# Remediating an ESXi host with PowerCLI

Tags: vmware, powercli

Code:

```
$baseline = "HPE 7.0U3f"
$vmhost = "HOSTNAME"

$baseline = Get-Baseline | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $baseline}
Attach-Baseline -Entity (get-vmhost $vmhost) -Baseline $baseline
$baseline | remediate-inventory -entity $vmhost -confirm:$false
```

Error:

> Update-Entity     The operation for the entity
> "HOSTNAME" failed with the following message: "The
> operation is not supported on the selected inventory objects. Check
> the events for the objects select ed for the operation."

Manually attaching the image and remediating the host works just fine. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check events in UI for this host, you will see error explanation.
2. Add parameter `-ClusterDisableHighAvailability:$TRUE` to remediate-inventory cmdlet.